# What is the order of priority amongst the OLE DB parameters in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parameters, etl

For an SSIS OLE DB connection manager, I can parameterize the server name, initial catalog, user name.

Instead of the above, I can as well Parametrize the connection string itself. Or I can parameterize all of them.

I am not able to find clear documentation advising which of the settings takes priority.

For example:

1. If `Server name` and `Connectionstring` are parameterized and I use serverA in server parameter, whereas I use `serverB` in `Connectionstring` parameter then what takes priority?
2. If either of the `Server name` or `Connectionstring` is parameterized and I use `serverA` in one and `serverB` in the other then what takes priority?
3. If none of them are parameterized and in the Connection manager suppose I use `serverA` in one (`Server name`) and `serverB` (`ConnectionString`) in the other then what takes priority?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find anything related in the official documentation. But I think that the parameters are prioritized based on the parameterized properties name. They are sorted in alphabetical order.

Let's say that the SSIS engine loop over all parameterized properties and evaluate the properties expression one-by-one before the execution. In Visual Studio (SSIS designer), all expressions are sorted based on the property's name.

[image]

#### 1st experiment

I added an OLE DB connection manager and parameterized the `ConnectionString` and `InitialCatalog` properties. When I click on the connection manager, on the properties tab, the expression is ordered by the property name:

[image]

Let's try to add a new expression on the `Description` property:

[image]

As shown in the image above, the expression is added in the third row in the expression grid. If I close the expression form, they are sorted by the property name, and the `Description` expression is moved to the second row:

[image]

Which means that the property name sorts them.

### 2nd experiment

I parameterized two properties of the OLE DB connection manager:

- ConnectionString: `Data Source=.\DATA;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;`
- Initial Catalog: `master`

I added an Execute SQL Task with the following command:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_CATALOG
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

And I configured the task to store The resultset within a variable named `User::database`.

Then, I added a breakpoint on the `onPostExecute` event, then visualized the `User:database` variable using a quick watch. As shown in the image below, the value is `master`.

[image]

This means that the Initial Catalog property in the OLE DB connection manager passed for the `Initial Catalog` property, not `Connection String`.

#### Conclusion

I don't think there is any logic implemented while evaluating all expressions in SSIS. The SSIS engine loops over the expressions based on the task properties' names.

Comment: Also it looks like it takes connection string as priority over server name

Comment: @variable 100% which also means that they are sorted alphabetically. I hope that this answer makes sense. Best of luck!